# Testing if an input iterator can write

Tags: c++, iterator, c++20, constexpr, static-assert

I made this `input iterator`

```
    template <typename T>
    struct input_iter: base_it<T> {
        private:
            typename base_it<T>::pointer _ptr;

        public:
            constexpr input_iter<T>() = default;
            constexpr explicit input_iter<T>(typename base_it<T>::pointer ptr = nullptr)
                : _ptr { ptr } {}
            constexpr ~input_iter<T>() = default;
            constexpr input_iter<T>(const input_iter<T>& other) = default;
            constexpr input_iter<T>(input_iter<T>&& other) noexcept = default;

            [[nodiscard]]
            constexpr auto operator=(typename base_it<T>::pointer ptr) -> input_iter<T>& { 
                _ptr = ptr; return *this; 
            }
            constexpr auto operator=(const input_iter<T>&) -> input_iter<T>& = default;
            constexpr auto operator=(input_iter<T>&&) noexcept -> input_iter<T>& = default;

            [[nodiscard]]
            constexpr auto operator*() const noexcept -> const typename base_it<T>::reference {
                return *_ptr;
            }

            [[nodiscard]]
            constexpr auto operator->() const noexcept -> const typename base_it<T>::pointer {
                return _ptr;
            }

            constexpr auto operator++() noexcept -> input_iter& {
                ++this-> _ptr;
                return *this;
            }

            constexpr void operator++(int) noexcept {
                ++(*this);
            }

            [[nodiscard]]
            constexpr friend auto operator==(const input_iter& lhs, const input_iter& rhs) noexcept -> bool {
                return lhs._ptr == rhs._ptr;
            }

            [[nodiscard]]
            constexpr friend auto operator!=(const input_iter& lhs, const input_iter& rhs) noexcept -> bool {
                return not (lhs == rhs);
            }
    };
```

Where you must assume (for now) that `base_iter` is `std::iterator`.

Well, one mandatory requirement for an `input_iterator` is that must be `indirectly_readable`. Since my `input_iter` doesn't belong to any concrete datastructure, and is in a module by itself, because I want to make it available for containers or ranges which is elements are stored in contiguous memory locations (but that's an story for another SO post) I would like to constraint the operation of writing things to the underlying container or range. So, my idea is the following:

```
template <typename T>
using base_it = std::iterator<std::input_iterator_tag, const T>;
```

*Note the const T, not T in the alias*

So whenever I try to write an stamement of this kind:

```
collections::Array arr = collections::Array<int, 5>{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
auto it_begin = arr.begin();

*it_begin = 7;
```

I am receving the error that I want, at compile time!

```
.\zero\tests\iterators\legacy\legacy_iterator_tests.cpp:47:28: error: cannot assign to return value because function
      'operator*' returns a const value
            *it_begin = 7;
```

Fine. But...

- I am doing idiomatically?
- Exists another better alternative?
- How could I write an `static_assert` and check that that expression doesn't compiles? I've seen complicated stuff going on with lambdas in the else block on an `if constexpr`, and some more using `SFINAE`, but I am not able to write it by myself. Can someone explain how to write it?

Code below is what I've tried so far, without obviously, no success. Take it as a meta-idea.

```
if constexpr (some_cond)
static_assert(
    *it_begin = 7, 
    "Wait... this is compiling! This shouldn't happen, since an input iterator musn't be able to performn write operations");
```

Comment: I got lost somewhere but, what does you iterator do that a `const T*` doesn't do? A `const T*` works as an interator in contiguous memory and you get a `const T&` if you dereference it.

Comment: `! requires(/*..*/){*it_begin = 7;}`?

Comment: @TedLygmo doesn't a `const T*` may be advanced an arbitrary number of non contiguous steps? Like `random_access_iterators` for std::list, for example? Btw, I just want to know how can I make a compile time test that "passes" whenever a piece of code won't compile (like `*it_begin = 7` for my input iter)

Comment: @Jarod42, thanks, but I am not being able of fully figure out your snip. Could you be more explicit? (C++ noob here)

Comment: @AlexVergara Yes a `const T*` is a random access iterator which most iterators that works on contiguous ranges are. `std::list` does _not_ have random access iterators though. The memory layout of `std::list` data is _not_ contiguous because it'd be impossible to fulfill the other requirements for `std::list` if it was.

Comment: @TedLyngmo sorry, I always confuse `std::list` with `std::array`, but yes, I just wanted to point out that `T*` is `random_access`.  So I understand that you would say that `T*` could is contiguous, not that it also can act as contiguous, because random access implies contiguous. Sorry about the confusion

Comment: @AlexVergara No problem! A random access iterator does not necessarily mean that the accessible data is contiguous though. One could for example store meta data between the user accessible data ([example](https://godbolt.org/z/MEvW4MY8d)) and it'd stlll be a random access iterator.

Comment: @TedLyngmo uh, thanks for sharing. Nice example

Comment: @AlexVergara You're welcome. I just noticed that `iterator operator++(int)` in my example is buggy (it copies `p` instead of `*this`) but you got the picture at least :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for the static assert: why not just use a concept if you're using C++20?
`{*d = from}` is the expression that has to compile while
`-> std::convertible_to<decltype(*d)>;` part is the optional type of that expression. It can be made to match the exact type with `same_as`, or can be just removed in case the type is irrelevant.

```cpp
#include <concepts>
#include <vector> //just for demonstration purposes

template<typename Dereferencable, typename From>
concept DereferencedAssignable = requires(Dereferencable d, From from)
{
    {*d = from} -> std::convertible_to<decltype(*d)>; //or std::same_as, depending on one's needs
};

static_assert(DereferencedAssignable<int*, int>);
static_assert(not DereferencedAssignable<const int*, int>);

static_assert(DereferencedAssignable<std::vector<double>::iterator, double>);
static_assert(not DereferencedAssignable<std::vector<double>::const_iterator, double>);
```

https://godbolt.org/z/8s44Gb3ME

As for being idiomatic:
I would opt for returning a copy of the previous value in the the postfix incrementation operator, but that might have been just a minor oversight here.

Comment: Concepts was my first try, but I wasn't able to figure out the correct syntax! Mostly because I was trying to make the concept generic enought to accept any expression

Comment: @AlexVergara I've seen a pretty general "check if that compiles" thing created using combined macros, lambdas and void_t. It can be done, sure. Is it worth it? It depends, for highly generic code, maybe. Feel free to open another thread for that if you need it.

Comment: one doubt. Why return a copy of the previous value in the postfix increment operator?

Comment: API predictability, conventions, you name it. Typically, the language allows usage like this: `int x = 3; int y = ++x; // y is 4`, `int x = 3; int y = x++; // y is 3`.

Comment: ah, sure. Good point. Thanks for spoting it!

Comment: You're welcome. BTW, I've seen your question deleted. Anyway, if you want to see the trickery, here it is in C++17 version: https://godbolt.org/z/1GnrrGsde
I haven't reworked it to concepts yet, I can post it here when I do ;)

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/qEG41fWbK and the C++20 version.

Comment: Wow, they are incredible. A lot of thanks for this! Unfortunately, the question is closed :( I would like to reopenit, so you could deserve the merit that you have for such incredible answers. Really, thank you dude

Comment: @AlexVergara don't mention it, some people prefer crosswords, I have C++ templates ;-) Glad I could have been helpful, cheers.